# calculate mean (or other function) per column for subsets of a matrix based on another matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, tapply

I am working in R with a classifier that outputs a matrix of real values with one column for each class that I am classifying. I then apply a function to the output matrix and my class label matrix (one column per class) to calculate an error per class (column).

This worked well with small datasets and equal distributions of class and non-class rows but breaks down when I use bigger files with a skewed distribution of class versus non-class.  Typically my files contain less than 0.3% class versus 99.7% non-class and in this case my classifier tends to simply output the non-class value (0).

I want to try a different error (cost) function to try to balance this out.  I will also try up and down sampling but they have other issues.  A possible simple change that I would like to try is to calculate the error for class 1 separately from class 0 and then combine those errors in such a way that the class errors are not buried by the overwhelming non-class errors.

I am including a minimum working example to help demonstrate what I want.

```
    L1 <- runif(13, min=0, max=1)
    L2 <- runif(13, min=0, max=1)
    predy <- cbind(L1, L2) # simulated output from the classifier
    #predy
    L1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    L2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    classy <- cbind(L1, L2) # Simulated class matrix
    #classy
    # Now compute error showing existing method
    mse <- apply((predy - classy)^2, 2, mean)
    nrmse <- sqrt(mse / apply(classy, 2, var))
    #
    #nrmse
    # L1       L2
    # 1.343796 1.062442
    #
    # Sort-of-code for what I would like to have
    # mse0 <- apply((predy - classy)^2, 2, mean) where x=0
    # mse1 <- apply((predy - classy)^2, 2, mean) where x=1
    # mse <- (mse0 + mse1) / 2   # or some similar way of combining them of my choice
    # nrmse <- sqrt(mse / apply(classy, 2, var))
```

In addition, my files are large and my classifier model is huge and so doing this in a computationally efficient manner would be very helpful.

I managed to do it using a for loop (below), can anyone help translate this to apply?

```
    mean.ones  <- matrix(0, dim(classy)[2])
    mean.zeros <- matrix(0, dim(classy)[2])
    for (ix in 1:dim(classy)[2]) {
        ix.ones <- classy[, ix]==1
        mean.ones[ix]  <- mean(predy[ix.ones, ix])
        mean.zeros[ix] <- mean(predy[!ix.ones, ix])
    }
```

The code above doesn't do the same thing as the original, it just calculates conditional means, however the code flow seems correct.

Comment: To add an additional complication, my method must work for a matrix with any number of columns.  My example shows two columns but the solution should work for one, two, three or any number of columns.  This was sort of why I did not use extract.

Comment: when you say "class and non-class rows", do you mean "case (1) and non-case  (0) rows"?

Comment: Managed to do it using a for loop, can anyone help translate this to apply?

Comment: Jthorpe - Thanks, yes (I think).  I guess we are using different terminology. Does my example using the for loop help?

Comment: Yes,  I added code that replicates the `mean.zeros` and `mean.ones` below.   If  `mse` stands for "mean squared error", then I don't think your code following the for loop is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that takes advantage of (1) lexical scoping so 
you don't have to pass the matrices to the summary function passed to the first `lapply()`, and 
(2) that `predy` and `classy` have the same dimensions.

Here's the calculation of the conditional means:

```
# calculation of means
temp <- lapply(seq.int(ncol(predy)),
               function(i)tapply(predy[,i],
                                 classy[,i],
                                 mean))
# presumably each column has members of both classes,
# but if not, we'll assure that there are two members 
# two each element of the list 'temp', as follows:
temp <- lapply(temp,
               function(x)x[match(0:1,names(x))])

# bind the outputs togeather by column.
mean_mx = do.call(cbind,temp)
all(mean_mx[1,]==mean.zeros)
all(mean_mx[2,]==mean.ones)
```

Here's the calculation of the mean squared errors:

```
# calculation of MSE
temp <- lapply(seq.int(ncol(predy)),
               function(i)tapply((predy[,i] - classy[,i])^2,
                                 classy[,i],
                                 mean))
# presumably each column has members of both classes,
# but if not, we'll assure that there are two members 
# two each element of the list 'temp', as follows:
temp <- lapply(temp,
               function(x)x[match(0:1,names(x))])

# bind the outputs togeather by column.
mse_mx = do.call(cbind,temp)

mse0 <- mse_mx[1,]
mse1 <- mse_mx[2,]
mse <- (mse0 + mse1) / 2 

nrmse <- sqrt(mse / apply(classy, 2, var))
```

Comment: Thanks Jthorpe.  I will try this then come back.

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion Jthorpe. Each class column only has zero or one as values.

Comment: Excellent Jthorpe, almost there.  I made minor edits to your code as your two alternate ways of calculating nrmse give different answers on my pc and your first suggestion (nrmse_correct) gives the same answer as my original code.  The denominator does have the same dimensions???  Thank you heaps for this!  I will need to sit down and try to understand it fully

Comment: In an earlier version of my code (I think prior to some of the edits to the OP?)  the dimensions were different, but that bit of code is now irrelevant, so I removed it.